# Electron child_process taking 10+ seconds on arm64

Tags: node.js, macos, electron

Electron 12.2.2 is running very slow when using `require("child_process").execSync()`:

- `ls` takes <10ms
- `diskutil unmount "/Volumes/NIKON D300"` takes over 10 **seconds**.

CPU usage doesn't spike and no new processes appear in activity monitor to indicate what is taking up that much time.

When I run `diskutil unmount "/Volumes/NIKON D300"` in normal terminal (default zsh) it takes **0.4s**:

```
time diskutil unmount "/Volumes/NIKON D300"
Volume NIKON D300 on disk4s1 unmounted
diskutil unmount "/Volumes/NIKON D300"  0.01s user 0.01s system 4% cpu 0.484 total
```

Computer: Apple M2 (arm64), 24gb ram, 1tb disk, Mac OS 13

It takes **1s** on an Intel i7 Macbook Pro 2018 with 32gb ram, so I'm trying to hunt down why it's taking so long and don't know where to look next.  Any advice is sincerely appreciated.

Breakout repo for how to reproduce it:
https://github.com/jsullivanlive/electron-slow-child-process

there are 2 buttons on the page, "ls" and "unmount" , and here's my console output when i click them:

[image]

---

Tried to upgrade libraries, watch console.app, activity monitor, etc.  Can't figure out why unmount is taking so much longer when run in child_process.

---

Created github issue in parallel in case it's actually a bug in electron: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/36254